# Add sound effects to audio and save it in Android

Tags: java, android, audio, edit, effects

I am using the ringdroid library to make a simple app that creates ringtones. I would like to add some functions: add fade in/out effects to current audio, and save it with new effects.

I have no idea how to do it, could you please help me?